Formal written form for a 2x something?
In a sentence where I want to say a title or position that has been awarded twice, how do I phrase it? For instance "He was a 2x runner-up for the Champion title", would it be "two time" or "2 time"? (For formal writing)
Another instance would be in a list such as, "She won a variety of titles including, Southeast Cheer Champ, 2x National Cheerleading Champion..."
In dialogue, it sounds like two time but Grammarly and Microsoft Word correct it to "times." Or have I just been saying it wrong? I have been researching, but have been unable to find anything helpful.

Why can't you use 'twice'? He was once/twice runner-up for the title.

ODE courtesy of Google has: one-time [adjective] ... 2. relating to a single occasion.
• "a one-time charge"

Please note that in any case, “2x” is wrong. Your meaning is correctly expressed in writing as “2×.” The multiplication sign is not a lowercase x, but the symbol ×.

The use of two-time implies deceit in my mind even if not intended. Avoid it.

The standard form is...

He was a two-time winner of...
(rarely ...a two-times winner)


Thank you! How would you word this in the form of a list, such as, "2x Champion, 3x nominee." Would it remain 2x?

Since you're asking about English, don't keep writing 2x, 3x - that's the language of mathematics. Your context is starting to look more like it should be the contents of a data table, but in the written version it would still be the three-time nominee.

If you were writing a list of someone's achievements or honours, it would be more normal to say "twice champion" or "(won) 2 championships". But that's different to the original question.

I would usually say “two times “ as a British speaker. I notice that “two time” is more common in US news reports. However, in your sentence neither sits well. So I suggest :
He was twice,  runner-up
Or
Or he was twice a runner up
Or my preferred option :
On two occasions , he was runner up

Thank you, I agree that neither suits that sentence. What would you suggest when including two times in a list where there are multiple titles? (I edited my prompt) For instance, if the list includes, "2x champion, 3x runner-up, 5x nominee..."

That is lending itself to a bulleted list or a table even - maybe not a sentence. When you see information like that in an article they usually give the position achieved and then the occasion in brackets. Eg speaking of my country’s soccer team …England -  UEFA finalists (2020, 2024)


For instance, in "He was a 2x runner-up for the Champion title", would it be "two time"?

No: you want "two-time runner-up" instead.
Incidentally, "two-times runner-up" is also incorrect.
Analogous examples:

a two-week vacation
a five-year ban
a three-act play
a seven-piece band
a three-button mouse
a five-star hotel
a five-year-old child
a three-inch-thick book.


In dialogue, it sounds like two time but Grammarly and Word correct it to "times."

In the above correction, the hyphen is not optional. Word/Grammarly might have thought that you want something like "he was a winner two times" (as opposed to "he was a winner two time"), which is indeed grammatical, but not actually what you are asking about.

@EdwinAshworth Sorry, in the link that you provided, what does "3rd person present: two-times" mean? Anyhow, are you saying that "I am a two-times champion" is acceptable even though "I stayed at a five-stars hotel and watched a three-acts play" clearly isn't?

Sorry; wrong usage. But FF gives some true counterexamples. Answers with endorsements / examples are always best. I remember that 'a nine days wonder' (no apostrophe) is one of various spellings licensed by some reference work. Kemp's original spelling preserved. // But I'd strongly advise your suggested spellings.

As already mentioned, an abbreviated 2× winner or 3× winner could be written
out as a two-time winner or three-time winner.  (Notice how small cardinal numbers are always spelt out as English words.)
But there are other possibilities to explore.
If he was a double winner and so won twice, making him twice a winner, then you could
also have a twice-over winner or a winner twice over and
such. And for your triple winner, if you’re especially courageous or want a bit of
a flourish, you could even shoot for a winner thrice over
or a thrice-over winner.
But there the multiplicative system for ‘how many times’
peters out, leaving us stuck with a ten-time winner or a
winner ten times over etc.
So we need a better system. Good thing we have one already.
Enter the ‑fold
It turns that we actually do have an existing multiplicative
suffix in English: ‑fold.  It has an authentically venerable
pedigree, and we can still use it freely today.
The OED says that the ‑fold
suffix
meaning ‘times’ can still be used productively to turn
any cardinal numeral (or adjective meaning ‘many’) into
the corresponding adjective, and at need, also adverb.
This
yields words like twofold (historically also sometimes
bifold or twinfold), threefold, tenfold, fivefold,
eightfold, twentyfold, sixtyfold, seventyfold, a hundredfold,
a thousandfold, a millionfold; manifold, multifold, myriadfold. You’ll even find instances of the open compound many fold for manifold.
(The more nonce-like the use, the more likely those will show up with a written hyphen for the new word, as in a seventy-fold increase. If your cardinal number already has a hyphen, though, like in some 25× winner, then you will need to not only retain it but also either make an open compound like a twenty-five fold winner or else  use another for the  ‑fold version, producing therefore a twenty-five-fold winner if you please.)
They also write how that suffix is probably cognate to Classical
Latin ‑plex, the one seen in simplex, duplex, triplex
meaning respectively once, twice, thrice. Latin multiplex
is where we ultimately got multiply from in the first place.
Random afterthoughts
I’ve always found it a bit of a shame that the ‑s adverbial
genitive from Old English is no longer productive. That’s
the one once upon a time used to derive once, twice, thrice;
since, hence, whence, thence; sideways, backwards, upwards,
afterwards; nowadays, arights, betimes, a-whiles.
They seemed to have stopped at thrice before they got to
force or *fifce or *tence.
On “Arthur, the ‘one-time’ and future king”
I honestly don’t know why
people today so often seem to forget to use once and twice
instead of one time and two time(s), but it can sometimes sound really odd when they do so, like what happens to the once-and-future king of the Britons under the new regime.
And while I suppose
I’ll give them a pass on a potential aversion to lovely thrice, that too would be nice,
at least every now and again.

In formal writing I would strongly recommend twice, as in 'twice National Cheerleading Champion', 'National Cheerleading Champion (twice),' or 'National Cheerleading Champion, twice,' depending on your personal preference and exactly what kind of formal writing you're doing.
'Two-time,' while correct and very similar to your original phrase, is quite informal, in my opinion.
As a side note, you shouldn't start a list with a comma. I'd rephrase your sentence to 'She won a variety of titles including Southeast Cheer Champ, twice National Cheerleading Champion...'
